Are fictionalists fairly required do away with realist language in the final theory?
This is something I've seen both levied at fictionalists and fictionalists claim is one of their major weaknesses. Justin Clarke Doane says roughly fictionalism is a research program that must come up with a way to describe the world without platonic language. And Kenny Boyce says of his own fictionalism that fact even fictionalists speak in platonic language is the greatest weakness of his position.
But language is multifaceted and among our most creative practices. Why would the lingo around math need to change to be a-platonic for fictionalism? What is so uncomfortable or dissonant about a final theory being struck in platonic lingo while not taking the lingo at face value? Pessimistically, did a bunch philosophers forget English class where language is a highly complex tool that does not rely on face-value. And are they claiming that math can escape discourse interpretation? Why not keep the brevity of propositional mathematical lingo, and wrap the whole domain of discourse in a non-face value interpretation?
Why don't realists have to give an account of propositions being taken at face-value, which is not obvious and not how propositions are always taken? Wouldn't a good English teacher demand an explanation why X set of propositions can be taken at face-value and Y set not be? The burden seems one sided against the fictionalist.
This isn't pro or against fictionalism, but wondering where the mandate propositions must be interpreted at face-value comes from.

There is no "platonic language". Realism as philosophy of math is not characterized by a specific "language". Does Kenneth Boyce give any examples to illustrate his claim?

@mudskipper Math is characterized by a specific language, such as using the existential quantifier ubiquitously. Mathematical language is replete with "there exists...". It's platonic existence because it says "exists" while understanding numbers don't exist like electrons do. Boyce means even though he thinks "there exist infinitely prime numbers" is technically false, he still communicates with mathematicians by saying "there exist infinitely many prime numbers" rather than "according to the fiction, there exist infinitely many primes". The fictional prepend is too cumbersome and not used

Philosophers have often equated reinterpretation with evasion. When fictionalists keep the language but reinterpret its commitments, it looks like they’re sidestepping the metaphysical burden. It feels more rigorous to reformulate mathematics in entirely non-Platonic terms, even if linguistically unnecessary, like Field's Science Without Numbers, Beckman's Math without Numbers...

@DoubleKnot Who gets to claim one is re-interpreting rather than interpreting, which we are all doing? Even propositions must be interpreted, and the face value-interpretation isn't always best--"It's rainy today" should be interpreted as "I think you should wear a coat dear" in many regular situations for example. Or "Even Sherlock Holmes didn't solve all riddles" -> "You're being too hard on yourself".

For mathematical realism, the default assumption is: Mathematicians talk as if sets, numbers, and functions exist because they do. Fictionalists are challenging this default assumption, so they’re the ones who must justify reinterpretation. The realist interpretation seems more natural because it aligns with how most people intuitively talk about mathematics. So the answer here is largely historical and philosophical inertia. OTOH your complaint is well-taken and realists have not been pressed hard enough to explain why mathematical language must be interpreted literally...
